# Missing autoconf/automake in Xcode 4.3?

Tags: development, xcode

After I purged Xcode 4.2 and installed Xcode 4.3 from App Store, I can not find autotools (automake/autoconf) through the command line. I've tried to run `find /Applications/Xcode.app -name 'automake'`, but apparently they are not there..

Does anyone knows what is Apple's point to remove these essential toolsets?

Answer (score 3):

For what it is worth- (and others stumbling onto this problem like I did) in the latest XCode (4.6, 4.5 and friends) autoconf is not even available in the command line tools.

I have manually installed just autoconf and a few friends, but still have trouble with some of the automake-ish software out there.

See http://jsdelfino.blogspot.com/2012/08/autoconf-and-automake-on-mac-os-x.html for a how-to to manually install.

Comment: Good call - I hadn't noticed it going missing.

Answer (score 2):

They moved them in 4.3 into a separate download afaik.

Try install the command line tools via Settings -> download.

[image]

Comment: I have Command Line Tools installed, but automake is still missing.

Answer (score 1):

I am running Mountain Lion and have XCode 4.5.2 installed.
I have installed ***autoconf*** using MacPorts:

```
sudo port install autoconf
```

I have not tried but I am sure that `sudo brew install autoconf` should also work for those that prefer Homebrew.

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain your `PATH` hasn't been corrupted? I've got the auto-tools in `/usr/bin` on my machine:

```
> ls -lah /usr/bin/auto*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    13K 16 May  2011 /usr/bin/autoconf
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   8.2K 16 May  2011 /usr/bin/autoheader
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    30K 16 May  2011 /usr/bin/autom4te
-rwxr-xr-x  2 root  wheel   227K 16 May  2011 /usr/bin/automake
-rwxr-xr-x  2 root  wheel   227K 16 May  2011 /usr/bin/automake-1.10
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    73K  3 Feb 21:55 /usr/bin/automator
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    20K 16 May  2011 /usr/bin/autoreconf
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    17K 16 May  2011 /usr/bin/autoscan
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    33K 16 May  2011 /usr/bin/autoupdate
```

Edit: it appears I did still have 4.2 on my machine. So this above is probably not helpful in the least.

---

You could try using the autoconf package from homebrew. It does not appear to be a keg that's available by default with homebrew, but you can still get it [from here](https://gist.github.com/1010716) by placing the following in to `/usr/local/Library/Formula/autoconf.rb`:

```
require 'formula'

class Autoconf < Formula
  url 'http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/autoconf/autoconf-2.13.tar.gz'
  homepage 'http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/'
  md5 '9de56d4a161a723228220b0f425dc711'

  def install
    system "./configure", "--program-suffix=213",
                          "--prefix=#{prefix}",
                          "--infodir=#{info}"
    system "make install"
  end
end
```

Comment: Here is mine..I installed Xcode 4.3 and even the [command line tools](http://kennethreitz.com/xcode-gcc-and-homebrew.html).  
`$ ls -lah /usr/bin/auto*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    73K Feb  1 16:28 /usr/bin/automator`

Comment: Have you uninstalled Xcode 4.2 entirely?

Comment: Good catch: no. I missed that, apologies. I appear to have 4.2 on my machine still.